# Error Handling with Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

I have what seems to be an error handling problem with his piece of code:

```
var err : NSError? = nil

captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

if err != nil {
    print("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

and I keep getting the following error on the captureSession line:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVCaptureDeviceInput' with an argument list of type '(device: AVCaptureDevice?, error: inout NSError?)'

I tried resolving the issue using this method:

```
let err : NSError?

do {
    err = try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
} catch _ {
    err = nil
}
```

yet I got another error on the first line of the do-catch statement:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'Void' (aka '()') to a value of type 'NSError?'

Any idea what might have went wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AVCaptureDeviceInput` has a single initializer called `init(device:)` and then it `throws` an `outError` if it is unable to initialize.

So you can either do `try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: someDevice)` which means you're "promising" that its not going to fail (will crash if it does). Or you can try/catch

```
do {
    try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: someDevice)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Update swift3
This is how we can handle it on swift3

```
        var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput()
        do {
              input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
              self.captureSession.addInput(input) 
           }
        catch {
              //  error
           }
```

Comment: You could just delete the first line if you want more optimal solution. The purpose was to show how you can handle the error throwing by AVCaptureDeviceInput in swift3.